# This возвращает объект windows

Tags: javascript

```
Core.drawRender = (function() {
    var i = 15;
    console.log(this);
    this.lifeScale(i);
    return function() {
        return i++;
    }
})();
```

Почему this это window? Не указывает на объект Core? Если, например, опустит this ниже во внутреннию функцию, то он будет указывать на объект Core.

Comment: @Andrey Perov, потому что замыкание исполняется и Core.drawRender присваивается только

    function() {
        return i++;
    }

а не все замыкание.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но не совсем понятно, как это связано с this...
____
Теперь все ясно, спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Проще говоря: в контексте самовызывающейся функции this указывает на объект window.

Answer (score 2):

[[@Andrey Perov](/users/23468/andrey-perov)](/users/23468/andrey-perov), ооок

Вот эта конструкция

```
(function() {
    var i = 15;
    console.log(this);
    this.lifeScale(i);
    return function() {
        return i++;
    }
})();
```

по факту говорит "JS, будь добр, выполни вложенную функцию и верни, что она там возвращает". Именно это и происходит: в глобальном контексте (js пока что вообще не волнует, что там слева) выполняется функция, поэтому this возвращает глобальный контекст - window.